# 12.04 upgrade to 12.10

Tags: 12.10, upgrade

I am a newbie to `Ubuntu` and not a techie. I have been working on **12.04** for a while without any problems. After being prompted to upgrade to **12.10**, i did but to my sorrow.

1st i had everything on my desktop except the `launchpad`. Following instructions from ask ubuntu, a lot of things happened. 12.10 seems to be installed because on the log in page left bottom corner it said **12.10**.But it did not except my password.

After following more instructions, i just have a blank purple screen, no place to log in

My laptop is a `ASUS N53S` with a `NVIDIA`.

Answer (score 1):

The 12.04 is an LTS  (long-term support), and is supported until 2017 ,the 12.10 is Not LTS , and no more supported , This upgrade was not a good idea , 
Before going deeep into issue details , 
I recommand that you download the 14.04 (LTS, supported until 2019) .

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 12.04 is an LTS (Long Term Support) version, meaning that it has 5 years of support. Ubuntu 12.10, however is not. It has already reached its end and is no longer supported by canonical.

You should have upgraded directly to 14.04, which is not only the newest version, but an LTS too.

In your case, I recommend, that you back up all of your important data using a live cd to an external drive or USB stick (if you haven’t already) and then do a fresh installation of Ubuntu 14.04.

You can find more help with the installation [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop).